# regexp monetary strings with decimals and thousands separator

Tags: php, regex

https://www.tehplayground.com/KWmxySzbC9VoDvP9

Why is the first string matched?

```
$list = [
    '3928.3939392',     //  Should not be matched
    '4.239,99',
    '39',
    '3929',
    '2993.39',
    '393993.999'
];

foreach($list as $str){
    preg_match('/^(?<![\d.,])-?\d{1,3}(?:[,. ]?\d{3})*(?:[^.,%]|[.,]\d{1,2})-?(?![\d.,%]|(?: %))$/', $str, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

## output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3928.3939392
)
Array
(
    [0] => 4.239,99
)
Array
(
    [0] => 39
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3929
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2993.39
)
Array
(
)
```

Comment: Why should it not be matched? What is the rule?

Comment: `(?:[,. ]?\d{3})*` matches like everything

Comment: For a detailed explanation of your current regex: https://regex101.com/r/ZoLUFf/1

Comment: The `(?<![\d.,])` is redundant as it always returns true: there can be no text before the start of the string. Try just [`^-?(?:\d{1,3}(?:[,. ]\d{3})*|\d+)(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/AFmdzp/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew create an answer.. beautiful pattern :p

Comment: but I would change `|\d+)` to `|\d*)` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to match the numbers as standalone strings, and thus, you do not need the lookarounds, you only need to use anchors.

You may use

```
^-?(?:\d{1,3}(?:[,. ]\d{3})*|\d*)(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AFmdzp/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `-?` - an optional `-`
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing alternation group:

  - `\d{1,3}(?:[,. ]\d{3})*` - 1 to 3 digits, followed with 0+ sequences of `,`, `.` or space and then 3 digits
  - `|` - or
  - `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `)` - end of the group
- `(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?` - an optional sequence of `.` or `,` followed with 1 or 2 digits
- `$` - end of string.